# Check one, some or all checkboxes and activate a proceed button does not work

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

The "check all" / "uncheck all" button lets me check or uncheck all checkboxes in my form. The "proceed..." button  should getting active as soon as one, more or all checkboxes are checked.

This works fine as long as I check the checkboxes manually but does not work when I use the "check all" button. In this case the "proceed..." button stays inactive.

I tried several other solutions with simliar results. Especially [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/2jszhdzw/1/) was very interesting but I was not able to change it to my needs.

Some help would be great.

I have the following HTML code.

```
<form id="container">
     <input type="button" class="check" value="check all">
     <input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="true"></input>
     <input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="true"></input>
     <input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="true"></input>
     <input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="true"></input>
     <button type="submit" id="proceedBut">proceed...</button>
</form>
```

with the following jquery code

```
$('.check:button').click(function(){
     var checked = !$(this).data('checked');
     $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
     $(this).val(checked ? 'uncheck all' : 'check all' )
     $(this).data('checked', checked);
});

var checkBoxes = $('#container .cb');
checkBoxes.change(function () {
    $('#proceedBut').prop('disabled', checkBoxes.filter(':checked').length < 1);
});
$('#container .cb').change();
```

Comment: `$('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked).trigger('change')`

Comment: You had the solution in your code already. At the end you fired an initial `change` event. Just do that inside the check all event handler. Note: As you code stands, you only need to fire `change` on a single checkbox and not all the checkboxes.

Answer (score 3):

Add `checkBoxes.first().change()` to the click event of `.check:button` to trigger the change event of first `.cb` like following.

```js
var checkBoxes = $('#container .cb');

$('.check:button').click(function() {
  var checked = !$(this).data('checked');
  $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
  $(this).val(checked ? 'uncheck all' : 'check all');
  $(this).data('checked', checked);

  checkBoxes.first().change();
});

checkBoxes.change(function() {
  $('#proceedBut').prop('disabled', checkBoxes.filter(':checked').length < 1);
});
checkBoxes.first().change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="container">
     <input type="button" class="check" value="check all">
     <input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="true"></input>
     <input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="true"></input>
     <input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="true"></input>
     <input class="cb" type="checkbox" value="true"></input>
     <button type="submit" id="proceedBut">proceed...</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Better solution, although you are firing more than one event (one per checkbox) when only one is needed (and `$('#container .cb')` is already in the `checkBoxes` variable) :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I've updated my answer. @GoneCodingGoodbye

Comment: I would suggest you move the `checkBoxes` variable to the top and reference it instead. e.g. `checkBoxes.first().change()`. This will minimise a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

checkboxes.change doesn't fire when clicking the check all button, added one line to the .check:button.click() event

```
$('.check:button').click(function(){
    var checked = !$(this).data('checked');
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
    $(this).val(checked ? 'uncheck all' : 'check all' )
    $(this).data('checked', checked);
    $('#proceedBut').prop('disabled', checkBoxes.filter(':checked').length < 1);
});
```

Comment: Works, but is a *less maintainable* solution than simply triggering a `change` event on one of the checkboxes (because you now need to maintain the same code in two places).